# Is creating a new table for each `list` the best way to speed up database queries here?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

My postgres database has a `lists` and `list_items` table. There is an index on the `list_id` column. To list all items in a list, I have been searching through `list_items` for where the `list_id` equals `id` from the `lists` table.

`lists`:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | "foo" |
| 1 | "bar" |

`list_items`:

| id | content | list_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "hello" | 0 |
| 1 | "world" | 1 |
| 2 | "foobar" | 0 |

However, as the number of lists and list items increases, it will take longer to search through `list_items` and match them to a list.

---

The current implementation will work for me. But suppose I wanted to speed things up. I was thinking of having an extra column in the `lists` table called `items_list`. When creating a list in the `lists` table, a new table will be created and the name stored in the `items_list`. When deleting a list, the table referenced by `items_list` will be dropped. It feels awkward, but it seems like a good way to speed up queries.

`lists`:

| id | title | items_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "foo" | "list_0_items" |
| 1 | "bar" | "list_1_items" |

`list_0_items`:

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | "hello" |
| 1 | "foobar" |

`list_1_items`:

| id | content |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | "world" |

If needed, is this a good way to speed up queries?

Are there other methods or databases (such as noSQL) that I should try instead?

Comment: how much data have you got?  It doesn't seem like you should be running into trouble unless you just have a massive amount.  What are your indexes like?  Also, see this link about asking database questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I don't have a lot of data, and I doubt I will need to change the current implementation. I was attempting to ask more theoretically; if I actually started running into trouble, would this be a good way to scale the database?

Comment: we have about a terabyte and a half of data,  and I've found that normalization and then using multiple joins to get the data back can break down in certain circumstances in terms of performance when the data gets large enough, so I will often denormalize on purpose.  I have never used noSQL.  so far mySQL has been sufficient.  I don't think creating and dropping tables is the way to go.   Hard to answer a hypothetical,  though.

Comment: Yeah, please provide some info about volume of your database and current speed of your queries. You need to have pretty huge db to have problems with such queries.

Comment: You can use table partitioning for this, a partition per list. For the outside world this doesn't change anything in how they query the table, just the way to data is stored is different. It can help, but you do need a (very) large amount of data to measure the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decisions like this always depend on how you think your final queries might end up.
Your initial solution works well in most cases provided you put indexes on the lookup  columns. Then you can just join the tables together using the ids when you run your searches. By putting list items into a single table you have the advantage of normalizing the data easily so a specific item only takes up space in your database once.

Sometimes you might categorise a table so it might get a subset of the data. Maybe all of the items that start with a letter, but you wouldn't do this sort of thing until the table reached a certain threshold. Your multiple solution does work, but you are going to need unions on lots of tables if you want to export the data together in a single query.

If you never need to lookup what the items are and just want to export them as is you could consider jsonb which allows you to put a json binary object directly into your row alongside the list details. You can query the items in the json but it is not as efficient as a indexed database column for quick lookups.
Using your example you would end up with a single table.

| id | title | list_items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "foo" | ['hello','foobar'] |
| 1 | "bar" | ['world'] |

If you had more data relating to each item then you can make the item the key or the value (depending on your use case) to make a dictionary or even go for a tree of data.

| id | title | list_items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "foo" | {'i1':'hello','i3':'foobar': null} |
| 1 | "bar" | {'i2':'world'} |

| id | title | list_items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "foo" | {'hello':{'note':'hello info'},'foobar': null} |
| 1 | "bar" | {'world':{'note':'some notes'}} |